# Regex line matching with prefix

Tags: python, regex

I'm current develop a GitHub hook to move some Zenhub issue placement when the commit message match certain string. What I'm trying to achieve is :

```
Progress #121, #128, #50
```

I want to extract the issue number here : 121, 128, 50 and the line must have a Progress prefix. Issue must be separated by comma, start with # and can have any number of prefix white space.

What I only achieved so far is this

```
^(?:Progress)(?:\s*#(\d+),?)+$
```

This only return to me the last capture group, which is 50 here.

I'd like to know where did I go wrong and how to achieve the desired outcome. Thank you.

EDIT : I wanted to used regex since I also wanted to solve these additional cases : "Progress" could start at middle of the string, or start of any line. If "Progress" start at the middle of the string, then I would have to check for any issue number after it.

So if there are any answer which solve this elegantly in Python ( other than regex ) is also welcome.

Comment: Do you need #50 as well?

Comment: Do you want it in JS or python?

Comment: Unfortunately, neither JavaScript nor Python support the match continuation anchor `\G` which would make this easy: `(?:^Progress\s+#|\G#)(\d+)(?:,\s+|$)`

Comment: @TimPietzcker Is that what it's called? Thanks!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I'm not sure if that's the "official" name.

Comment: @Gurman yes, I did miss that. I wanted all the issue number.

Comment: @TimPietzcker which language can support that ?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm more interested in Python since I'm much more familiar with it. An JS answer is still acceptable.

Comment: Off the top of my head: All .NET languages, Java, Perl (and other implementations that use PCRE), PHP, R, Ruby...but there certainly are others. It's a fairly standard tag by now, but Python and JavaScript haven't updated their regex engines in ages. For Python, there's the [`regex` module (PyPI)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) that was once set to replace the `re` module - no idea when/if that will happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a regex to match an entire pattern, and extract repeating sub-patterns from it at the same time. I'm not sure you can do both at the same time - it's either one or the other.

If you're using Python, I'd recommend making this easy. Use a simple `str.startswith` check and then extract issue numbers with regex.

```
if string.startswith('Progress'):
    return re.findall('#(\d+)', string)
```

Which should return `['121', '128', '50']`. You can adapt a similar methodolgy if you're working with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought of this solution but I wanted to used regex I think it is better to solve multiple other cases like : "Progress" could start at middle of the string, or start of any line. If "Progress" start at the middle of the string, then I would have to check for any issue number after it.

Comment: @SơnĐỗĐìnhThy you could do: if “Progress” in string: .... and repeat the same thing. Why not?